# Android memory consumption increasing issue

Tags: java, android, memory, android-intent, garbage-collection

When I testing my app performance, especially memory test, java memory allocation is getting increased while we are switching between activities. **After facing this issue I created a testing application that includes only a button for switch between activities and the issue is the same**. It can be seen by [Android Profile moniter](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler). Please see below image,

[image]

Above red arrows edges are, starting new activities. Although cleared task and set flags as a new task, it will increase the memory, But whenever we clear the task stack, the garbage collector should wipe the non-reference data from memory.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

I use the above flags to clear task and in additionally I used

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

There is no shared variables or objectives in each activity and those activities only contains just a button to go to another activity.

What are the solutions and good practices to avoid this issue?

Comment: Do you use any static methods?

Comment: No, In those activities there is no any method or variable that created by me. Just only `onCreate()` and a button to go next activity.

Comment: Is there a lot of UI or graphics involved in the new activity like maps?

Comment: No. Every activity has one and only attribute, that's a button to go the next activity

Comment: Create a test application and switch between activities to see if you get the same result.

Comment: @HB. After I faced this issue, I created a test application and the result is given above. I'll mention that in the thread.

Comment: And you are running the app on a real device? Not an emulator?

Comment: Yeah, In a real device. Samsung Galaxy S6 edge, SM-G92dF and Android Version 7